# Magento 2 error: MiBsyntax error, unexpected ')', expecting variable in vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428)

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, composer

I am a bigginer in magento 2
I came across with this error when hit

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

[image]

Looks like the issue is inside the `ClassLoader.php` file so i remove the `classLoader.php` and past the code from this link https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/main/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.php into `ClassLoader.php` file which should work after this command but could not resolve the issue.

Please give me your suggesstion

`Composer -v` is `2.4.4`

Answer (score 0):

You have run **composer update** command, and as a result versions your third-party modules in vendor folder  are upgraded to upper versions. You can confirm it by comparing your current composer.lock file with composer.lock file before running  **composer upadte** command. Their newer versions is not compatible to the Magento code, so now you need to downgrade your vendor folder module as before. Then run s:d:c command will start working.
You can restore your previous composer.lock file, than run **composer install** command, which will download modules version from composer lock file. The idea is never use **composer update** command as it changes your modules version, use **composer install**  command it take version from your composer.lock file and versions remain the same.